# Is a torus a closed set? $0<r<R$ (Cartesian coordinates). Proof generalization. Describing the surface of the torus.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

A torus in Cartesian coordinates is described by the [equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus#Geometry) $$(x^2+y^2+z^2+R^2-r^2)^2-4R^2(x^2+y^2)=0,$$
so I could also write the torus as the set $T=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3|(x^2+y^2+z^2+R^2-r^2)^2=4R^2(x^2+y^2)\} $

I'm working on an exercise where it would be useful to show that the torus is not an open set.
Visually, it seems obvious that (for example) the point $(r+R, 0,0)$ is a point on the boundary of the torus:

Let $\varepsilon>0$ with $\epsilon < r$ be arbitrary :

$\boldsymbol{(i)}$

$U_\varepsilon(r+R, 0,0)\cap T\neq \emptyset$ because $(r+R-\frac{\epsilon}{2}, 0,0)\in T$ and $ (r+R-\frac{\epsilon}{2},0,0)\in U_{\epsilon}(r+R,0,0)$

$\boldsymbol{(ii)}$

$(r+R+\frac\epsilon2,0,0)\in\Bbb R^3\setminus T$ and $(r+R+\frac\epsilon2,0,0)\in U_\epsilon(r+R, 0,0)$ i.e. $U_\epsilon(r+R, 0,0)\cap \Bbb R^3\setminus T\neq \ \emptyset$

$\boldsymbol{(i)}$ and $\boldsymbol{(ii)}\Rightarrow\ (r+R, 0,0)\in \partial T$ (is a point on the boundary of the torus).

I want to show that this is the case for all points on the surface of $T$, but how can I generalize my proof for the points $\neq (r+R, 0,0)$ on the surface of $T$ ?

I'm having trouble describing the surface of the torus.

**It is important that the surface is described in Cartesian coordinates.**

Comment: The inverse image of a closed set ($\{0\}$ here) under a continuous function is a closed set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As copper.hat comments, the torus is the inverse image of $\{0\}$ of the continuous map
$$f : \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R, f(x,y,z)= (x^2+y^2+z^2+R^2-r^2)^2-4R^2(x^2+y^2) .$$
Thus $T$ is closed in $\mathbb R^3$ and since $T \ne \emptyset,\mathbb R^3$ it cannot be open in $\mathbb R^3$. In fact it is a two-dimensional smooth submanifold of $\mathbb R^3$ (and thus cannot have any interior points), but this fact requires some knowledge about differential geometry.

Anyway, it is easy to see that $T$ does not have interior points.

Note that $x^2+y^2+z^2+R^2-r^2 > 0$ for all $(x,y,z)$. Now assume that $(x,y,z)$ is an interior point of $T$. Then there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that $U_\epsilon(x,y,z) \subset T$. In particular $(x,y,z\pm\epsilon/2) \in T$. But this implies
$$(x^2+y^2+z^2+R^2-r^2)^2 = (x^2+y^2+(z\pm\epsilon/2)^2+R^2-r^2)^2$$
hence
$$x^2+y^2+z^2+R^2-r^2 = x^2+y^2+(z\pm\epsilon/2)^2+R^2-r^2 $$
and thus
$$z^2 = (z\pm\epsilon/2)^2 .$$
For $z = 0$ this is trivially impossible. For $z \ne 0$ at least one of $z+\epsilon/2$ and $z-\epsilon/2$ has the same sign as $z$ and we conclude $z = z+a\epsilon/2$ with $a=1$ or $a=-1$. This is impossible.